# npm install react-google-login version problem

Tags: react-google-login

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: shareme_frontend@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16 || ^17" from react-google-login@5.2.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react-google-login
npm ERR!   react-google-login@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

**`npm ERR! peer react@"^16 || ^17" from react-google-login@5.2.2`**

is this important?

I used

```
npm install react-google-login --legacy-peer-deps
```

to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, `react-google-login` requires `react` 16 or 17 (with an arbitrary minor version), but your project has `react` 18.2.0.

You can solve the error by explicitly installing an older version, e.g.:

```
npm install react@17
```